# How to bypass sudo password prompt at login?

Tags: sudo, login, password

I'm using a fresh install of Linux Mint 18.1 Cinnamon.

I'd like to run the VPN client Mullvad at startup. It requires me to enter a super user password to run `/usr/bin/mtunnel`, and I'd rather not have to enter this every single reboot.

I tried adding the exceptions below to the bottom line of the `/etc/sudoers` file using `visudo`, but nothing has changed.

```
myUsername ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/mullvad
myUsername ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/mtunnel
```

Maybe this doesn't use `sudo` then?  I'm new to Linux, so any tips would be appreciated.

Any ideas on how to get something that requires super user privileges to run at startup without requiring a password?

Comment: Are you sure it's related to sudo?  How do you run it at startup exactly?

Comment: If it wants a *super-user password* (not yours) it's not running `sudo`.

Comment: Okay.  I'm brand-new to Linux so I have a lot of reading to do.  I run it from Linux Mint's "Startup Applications" application, but I also tried adding a call to the end of rc.local and "@reboot /usr/bin/mullvad" to the end of root's crontab.

Answer (score 0):

This is more strict:

```
 myUsername ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/mullvad
 myUsername ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/mtunnel
```

This is more open:

```
 myUsername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/mullvad
 myUsername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/mtunnel
```

Comment: I tried that, but got the same result.  I'm assuming it's using sudoers, but maybe it's not.  It's a popup window saying "Authentication is needed to run /usr/bin/mtunnel as the super user."

Comment: I tried adding @reboot /usr/bin/mullvad to my root crontab and also adding /usr/bin/mullvad to rc.local, but it still isn't running.